# Unit Testing a Function Macro

Tags: c, unit-testing, macros

I'm writing unit tests for some function macros, which are just wrappers around some function calls, with a little housekeeping thrown in.

I've been writing tests all morning and I'm starting to get tedium of the brainpan, so this might just be a case of tunnel vision, but:

Is there a valid case to be made for unit testing for macro expansion? By that I mean checking that the correct function behavior is produced for the various source code forms of the function macro's arguments. For example, function arguments can take the form, in source code of a:

- literal
- variable
- operator expression
- struct member access
- pointer-to-struct member access
- pointer dereference
- array index
- function call
- macro expansion
- (feel free to point out any that I've missed)

If the macro doesn't expand properly, then the code usually won't even compile. So then, is there even any sensible point in a different unit test if the argument was a `float` literal or a `float` variable, or the result of a function call?

Should the expansion be part of the unit test?

Comment: Definitely, if you forgot to put parentheses around each and every instance of the macro arguments. Otherwise, not so much. But really, this is mostly a matter of opinion, or at least a case-by-case decision.

Comment: Using expressions such as `value & 1` could reveal that the macros are careless, but code inspections can do that too. I think going through the full panoply of tests is overkill; the tedium is giving you a relevant warning.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yeah, I have to watch myself sometimes. I get way into the groove covering edge cases and ticking all the boxes that if I'm not careful, I'll wind up writing tests to cover solar eclipses and invasions from Mars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47848573/unit-testing-a-function-macro#comment82661579_47848573):

> Using expressions such as `value & 1` could reveal that the macros are careless, but code inspections can do that too.
>
> I think going through the full panoply of tests is overkill; the tedium is giving you a relevant warning.

There is an additional mode of checking that might be relevant, namely side-effects such as: `x++ + ++y` as an argument.  If the argument to the macro is evaluated more than once, the side-effects will probably be scrambled, or at least repeated.  An I/O function (`getchar()`, or `printf("Hello World\n")`) as the argument might also reveal mismanagement of arguments.

It also depends in part on the rules you want to apply to the macros.  However, if they're supposed to look like and behave like function calls, they should only evaluate arguments once (but they should evaluate each argument — if the macro doesn't evaluate an argument at all, then the side-effects won't occur that should occur (that would occur if the macro was really a function).

Also, don't underestimate the value of `inline` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and some of the points made in @Jonathan Leffler's answer, I've come to the conclusion that this is something that is better tested in functional testing, preferably with a fuzz tester.

That way, using a couple of automation scripts, the fuzzer can throw a jillion arguments at the function macro and log those that either don't compile, produce compiler warnings, or compile and run, but produce the incorrect result.

Since fuzz tests aren't supposed to run quickly (like unit tests), there's no problem just adding it to the fuzz suite and letting it run over the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of testing is to find errors.  And, your macro definitions can contain errors.  Therefore, there is a case for testing macros in general, and unit-testing in particular can find many specific errors, as will be explained below.

Code inspection can obviously also be used to find errors, however, there are good points in favor of doing both: Unit-tests can cheaply be repeated whenever the respective code is modified, say, for reactoring.

Code inspections can not cheaply be repeated (at least they cause more effort than re-running unit-tests), but they also can find other points that tests can never detect, like, wrong or bad documentation, design issues like code duplication etc.

That said, there are a number of issues you can find when unit-testing macros, some of which were already mentioned.  And, it may in principle be possible that there are fuzz testers which also check for such problems, but I doubt that problems with macro definitions are already in focus of fuzz-testers:

- wrong algorithm: Expressions and statements in macro definitions can just be as wrong as they can be in normal non-macro code.
- unsufficient parenthesization (as mentioned in the comments): This is a potential problem with macros, and it can be detected, possibly even at compile time, by passing expressions with operators with low precedence as macro arguments. For example, calling `FOO(x = 2)` in test code will lead to a compile error if `FOO(a)` is defined as `(2 * a)` instead of `(2 * (a))`.
- unintended multiple use of arguments in the expansion (as mentioned by Jonathan): This also is a potential problem specific to macros.  It should be part of the specification of a macro how often its arguments will be evaluated in the expanded code (and sometimes there can no fixed number be given, see `assert`).  Such statements about how often an argument will be evaluated can be tested by passing macro arguments with side effects that can afterwards be checked by the test code.  For example, if `FOO(a)` is defined to be `((a) * (a))`, then the call `FOO(++x)` will result in `x` being incremented twice rather than once.
- unintended expansion: Sometimes a macro shall expand in a way that causes no code to be produced.  `assert` with `NDEBUG` is an example here, which shall expand such that the expanded code will be optimized away completely.  Whether a macro shall expand in such a way typically depends on configuration macros.  To check that a macro actually 'disappears' for the respective configuration, syntactically wrong macro arguments can be used: `FOO(++ ++)` for example can be a compile-time test to see if instead of the empty expansion one of the non-empty expansions was used (whether this works, however, depends on whether the non-empty expansions use the argument).
- bad semicolon: to ensure that a function like macro expands cleanly into a compound statement (with proper do-while(0) wrapper but without trailing semicolon), a compile time check like `if (0) FOO(42); else ..` can be used.

Note: Those tests I mentioned to be compile-time tests are, strictly speaking, just some form of static analysis.  In contrast to using a static analysis tool, such tests have the benefit to specifically test those properties that the macros are expected to have according to their design.  Like, static analysis tools typically issue warnings when macro arguments are used without parentheses in the expansion - however, in many expansions parentheses are intentionally not used.